# Can't set proper path to app.js

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

I'm developing webapp in Java with angularjs. My problem is that I'm getting 404 on app.js and app.css files.

path to index.html

```
webapp/WEB-INF/app/pages/index.html
```

path to app.js

```
webapp/WEB-INF/app/js/app.js
```

path to app.css

```
webapp/WEB-INF/app/css/app.css
```

connecting css and script in html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/app.css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

what should be the proper path?

Comment: These are all static resources, have you tried to use something like: <mvc:resources> ?

Comment: uder WebContent add index.html page. add sub folder in webContent .ex scripts is the sub folder. app.js under the script. add links to index.html page.  <script src="./scripts/app.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I've fonud the solution. I was using lineman and lineman creates the real index.html in "generated" folder.